# why isn't a set with different type of elements applicable for the iteration?

Tags: scala

```
val signList1 = Set("(", "[", " VIA ")
val signList2 = Set('(', '[', " VIA ")
val returnStr2 = "xx VIA yy" 
var returnStr3 = returnStr2  
signList2.foreach(e => {
   val pos = returnStr2.indexOf(e)
   if (pos == 0) {
     returnStr3 = returnStr2.substring(pos + 1).trim
   }
   else if (pos > 0) {
     returnStr3 = returnStr2.substring(0, pos).trim
   }
}) 
println(returnStr3)
```

returnStr3 is supposed to be `xx` whereas it is given `xx VIA yy` if I use signList2 while it is given `xx` when i use `signList1`.
Why is this phenomenon? Appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that signList2 is a `Set[Any]`.  This in turn means that in the `foreach`, `e` is an `Any` (equivalent to `java.lang.Object`), this makes the normal `java.lang.String.indexOf` methods (which need a `char` or a `String` as an argument) inapplicable (even though all the objects in `signList2` are either char or String, their common supertype is Any, so that's all that's known about them).

Instead Scala implicitly converts `returnStr2` to an instance of `scala.collection.immutable.StringOps`, which ends up having an `indexOf` method which takes an `Any`.  This results in trying to compare a String to a Char which fails.

You can get the result you seek by forcing `e` to be a String in the indexOf call (e.g. by calling `e.toString`).

In general, having a type that infers to `Any` is a bad code smell (arguably except for Akka, where you sort of have to grin and bear it (or transition to Akka Typed)).  Most if not all Scala linters will flag an expression whose type has an `Any` in it.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!

Comment: The signature `def indexOf[B >: Char](elem: B): Int` in `StringOps` indeed does look a bit astonishing. Any idea what the parameter `B` is good for, except searching for `Any` in a `String`, and generating incomprehensible error messages? O_o? Ah! I know! Let's just blame it on covariance :)